# Why column name with Many to Many relationship doesn't get retrieved? SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have the following model:

```
class Actividad(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Actividad"

    codigo = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    productos = relationship("Producto_Actividad")
    total = Column(Float)
```

Which has a Many to Many relationship (through an association table called "Producto_Actividad") with another model (called "Producto") in the field "productos".

For getting the columns of this model's objects I'm using:

```
Actividad.__mapper__.column_attrs.keys()
```

Or (being "act" an instance of the model):

```
act.__table__.columns
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting the following results:

```
['codigo', 'total']
```

Why am I not getting the "productos" field in the results set? I'm needing this to be used in another section of my program.

Comment: Difficult to tell with so little information. Please share **all** relevant code and data. See: [mcve], [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Although, I've already received a satisfactory answer from @Gord Thompson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I not getting the "productos" field in the results set?

Because there is no column representing "productos" in the "Actividad" table. That linkage is in the (separate) association table where rows will match one or more "Producto_codigo" values with one or more "Actividad_codigo" values.

Comment: Thanks for the satisfactory explanation. I was able to find out how to get all the fields (including the associations) for one model. In case anyone is interested in: Creating a list that includes both Model.__mapper__.column_attrs **and** Model.__mapper__.relationships